# Kivy Widget positioning in ScrollView

Tags: python, kivy

I have a label in a gridlayout in a scrollview. My goal is to draw a diagonal slash (among other things) through the label in code (as opposed to in the .kv file). I've been trying to accomplish this with

```
with l.canvas: #l is my label
    Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    Line(points=[l.x, l.y, l.x+l.width, l.y+.height], width=1.2, cap='square')
```

However, this produces a red line that starts in the bottom left of the screen, at position (0, 0), and is nowhere near the label. If I had to guess at the issue, I'd guess the problem is that the position is in terms of the scrollview and I'd want the positioning to be from the grid layout. I've tried using `l.to_local`, `l.to_parent`, `l.to_widget`, and `l.to_window`, but they all return (0, 0). How do I get the correct position of the label, so that the line is inside the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say *where* this code is written, but I guess it's at the same time as `__init__` of the widget.

Assuming so, this is because the widget position *is* `0, 0` until its parent sets it (e.g. a BoxLayout rearranging its children in a row), which happens after `__init__`. That is, the line is drawn in the right place at the time of drawing, but the label is moved later and the line stays in the same place because you didn't tell it to do anything else.

You can resolve this by keeping a reference to the line and resetting its points when stuff changes.

```
with l.canvas: #l is my label
    Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    l.line = Line(points=[l.x, l.y, l.x+l.width, l.y+.height], width=1.2, cap='square')
l.bind(pos=line_reset_func, size=line_reset_func)
```

...where you obviously have to define your line_reset_func that takes two arguments (I think the label instance and new pos or size value) and changes the points of `instance.line`. This might most naturally be a method of `l`, if you define your own Label subclass.

kv takes care of this automatically, which keeps things simpler and is one reason we recommend using it wherever possible.

Comment: That fixes everything. Thank you